# Reductive Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Does it exist a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ that is reductive but if we consider the inclusion of Lie agebras $\mathfrak{g} \subset \mathfrak{h}$ then $\mathfrak{g}$ is not reductive in $\mathfrak{h}?$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the definition of when a Lie subalgebra
is reductive in a Lie algebra. Please can you remind us of it?

Comment: I found it in Diximier :"enveloping algebras". $\mathfrak{g}$ is reductive in $\mathfrak{h}$ if the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple in $\mathfrak{h}$.

Comment: If you read Dixmier further, you'll see that if g is reductive in h, a semisimple module over h restricts to a semisimple module over g. Thus if g does not act semisimply on V, it cannot be reductive in gl(V). Now let g be one-dimensional, spanned by a non-semisimple endomomorphism...

Comment: By the way, in representation theory nearly always $h\subset g$, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reductive Lie algebra $L$ is the direct sum of a semisimple
Lie algebra $L_1$ and an abelian Lie algebra $L_2$. Let's consider
the case where $L_2$ is one-dimensional.
We can embed $L$ into a larger Lie algebra $L=L_1\oplus L_2'$
by embedding $L_2$ into $L_2'$. Let $L_2'$ be the two-dimensional
Lie subalgebra
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
*& *\\\
0& 0
\end{array}
\right)$$
of $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbf{C})$
and
$$L_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0& *\\\
0& 0
\end{array}
\right).$$
Then $L_2$ does not act semisimply on $L_2'$, so $L$ does not
act semisimply on $L'$.

Comment: An abelian algebra is reductive by definition, so $L_1$ is not needed. 

Answer (score 5):

As remarked by Jim Humphreys in a comment to [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23085/on-the-full-reducibility-of-representations-of-reductive-lie-algebras/23097#23097) to [a previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23085/on-the-full-reducibility-of-representations-of-reductive-lie-algebras), the notion of *reductive* for a Lie algebra (in characteristic zero) has no intrinsic interest, which means that the answer to this question has to be positive.

Here is one possible construction.  Let $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{s} \oplus \mathfrak{z}$ be a reductive Lie algebra, where $\mathfrak{s}$ is semisimple and $\mathfrak{z}$ is the centre of $\mathfrak{g}$.  Consider a representation $V$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ where $\mathfrak{z}$ does *not* act semisimply.  Now let $\mathfrak{h}$ be the semidirect product $\mathfrak{g} \ltimes V$, with $V$ abelian.

Comment: Isn't "yes" a positive answer?

Comment: Oops. Must have inverted the question in my mind.  Thanks!  I've edited it now.
